# What is the approximate hashrate of a human?

Tags: hashpower, mining-theory

Which and how much mathematical operations are required for the blockheader-to-blockhash operation and how fast would a human be able to calculate a single hash?

EDIT: For simplicity, I think it's a good idea to use the world record for mathematical calculations to make it a little more fair.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The user C121 on r/bitcoin explored this topic in the thread [Mining Bitcoin by hand](http://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/1r3wau/mining_bitcoin_by_hand/).

He states that it takes 3385 integer operations to calculate one double SHA-256 hash.

His conclusion was that you would reach **about 0.00003 H/s**, or in other terms, **it would take about 9.4 hours for one hash**, assuming the human in question could do a 32-bit operation in 10 seconds.

He also estimates that you would fill about **seventy pages of paper** with the calculations per hash.

Update:
As Mathias711 pointed out in the comments, Ken Shirriff actually calculated some SHA-256 operations manually and wrote an [article about mining bitcoin with pencil and paper](http://www.righto.com/2014/09/mining-bitcoin-with-pencil-and-paper.html). He arrives at an estimate of **0.67 hashes per day**, at a vastly uncompetitive energy consumption. ;)

Comment: Hmm, with a bit of pre-made *tools* (mechanical or not), we can actually steeply reduce this number right?

Comment: Do ASICs qualify as 'tools'?

Comment: [This guy](http://www.righto.com/2014/09/mining-bitcoin-with-pencil-and-paper.html) actually did it, and he reached 0.67 hashes / day.

Comment: I was actually just about to link this myself. I'm sure with practice you'd increase the number but humans make mistakes after hashing for long periods of time, I'm sure.